# Gráfica con Angular.js

Tags: javascript, html5, chart.js

Buenas tardes, en este momento me encuentro desarrollando una app web donde necesito generar la grafica de unos datos , necesito saber de que manera puedo pasarle un array con la informacion a la data que grafica , ejemplo tengo el array y tengo el codigo de la grafica:

```
arrayData=[];---> estos dos array ya tienen la información
arrayLabel=[];-->"
```

//Mi intencion es pasarle el arrayLabel como los labels que van sobre el eje 
     x y el arrayData para que ese sea el valor graficado.

```
require(['assets/bower_components/chart.js/dist/Chart.min.js'], function(Chart){
      var ctx = $("#myChart");
      var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
          type: 'bar',
          data: {
              borderWidth:2,
              labels: [arrayLabel],
              datasets: [{

                  data: [arrayData],
                  } 
              ]
          },
          options: {
              scales: {
                  yAxes: [{
                      ticks: {
                          beginAtZero:true
                      }
                  }]
              }
          }
      });
    })
```

Comment: Y cuál es el error?

Answer (score 0):

Estoy haciendo un sistema muy similar
primero necesitaras descr¿argar el motor de las graficas
En mi caso te recomiendo nvd3 ya que tiene muchas graficas completas y sencillas de manejar

Si ya lo tienes instalado, puedes cambiar el array que contiene la grafica, y envia por medio de otra funcion los valores

```
data:
                [
                    /**
                     * Estructura de datos
                     * |------------------|------------------------|
                     * |        x         |     nombre de valor    |
                     * |------------------|------------------------|
                     * |        y         |     Valor de datos     |
                     * |------------------|------------------------|                             
                     */
                ]
```

con esta funcion por ejemplo enviarias los datos a data[] de la grafica linechart, x y y son los datos que lee el motor grafico

```
$scope.generateLineChartData = function (values, name)
{
//values: es un vector en el que tengo un conjunto
//name: el nombre que aparecera en la estructura de datos
    var line = []

    //Data is represented as an array of {x,y} pairs.
    for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
        line.push({x: i, y: values[i]});
    }

    //Line chart data should be sent as an array of series objects.
    $scope.data.push({
        values: line, //values - represents the array of {x,y} data points
        key: name, //key  - the name of the series.
    });
};
```

Espero te sirva, o hablame por aqui para poder explicarte mejor
Suerte

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu ayuda , ya logre resolverlo , ahora tengo un pequeño problema con las graficas , lo que sucede es lo siguiente , tengo una lista donde dicha lista en cada elemento tiene un boton que muestra en unas pestañas mas informacion sobre cada elemento , siempre que se le da click en el boton se carga en una pestaña la grafica que he realizado , la cuestion es que esa grafica cada que la muestro una vez y regreso a la lista a mirar otro item se recarga la grafica pero encima de la que ya existia, alguna ayuda ?

Comment: @FABIANAGUILAR, espera haber si te entendi, colocas la primera grafica y te funciona bien, pero cuando colocas la segunda grafica, te la pone sobre la grafica que ya habia puestos anteriormente, es así?

Comment: @FABIANAGUILAR
Mira eso se resuelve creando un servicio, en el crearas un vector vacio
`app.service('DataService', function ()
{
    this.data = [];
});`
instancias el service
`$scope.service = GraphsService;`
en este vector guardaras como objeto cada grafica, diferenciando cada grafica con id
`if ((id == "Graf-1"))
        {
            $scope.service.graphs.push(GraphsService.lineChart());
            $scope.$apply();
        }
Con el push`añades el objeto linechart dentro del vector graphs... 
Con el $scope.$apply(); aplicas los cambios

Comment: @FABIANAGUILAR

Por ultimo, todos los graficos estan en un servicio `app.service('GraphsService', function ()`
de alli es donde consigues el objeto para graficarlo

Por favor intentalo, y si tienes dudas, no dudes en preguntar